# When you say US Large for shirt size, how should I scale it for a UK Large? 2:1?

Tags: discussion

This is mostly a cheeky dig at our friends across the pond :P (not really meant to offend anyone), but I also really don't want to get a t-shirt that doesn't fit after 6 - 8 weeks of waiting.

So, can I get some kind of idea on the size please? How big is the difference between large, extra large and double extra large? Do you haz teh code?

[image]

Seriously, it's different standards in most retail outlets, so not unlikely to be even more different from country to country.

Comment: No idea what a UK large is like, but I'm 6'4"/190lb (190cm/86kg) (0.38 rods/13.5 stones) and I wear a US large if that's any help

Comment: I found a [t-shirt size conversion chart](http://www.meixsell.com/EbayInfo/WWconversion.html). No idea if it's accurate, but it's something.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Unfortunately, those numbers it displays as being European sizes tell me nothing. We usually work with S/M/L etc. as well, but the scales are different, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the size of the shirt I got today, which should have been an M, There is a marked difference between US and EU sizes. In EU sizes, this could have been an XL or an L at least.

But... who am I to complain. Swag! :D

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI even if you find a conversion to base it on it would depend on the shirt and the material it is made with...  So keep that in mind if you are wanting something for longevity.